# ColumnListItem - Event Handler "press" NOT Triggered

Tags: sapui5

I am using ColumnListItem to display a list of Sales Orders in Overview.view.xml. When the user clicks on an item of the list (of Sales Orders), the App should navigate to the Detail.view.xml.

I have defined the `onPress` event handler in Overview.Controller.js. But the App did not execute the function (I put an `alert()` there and it was not triggered). Why the `onPress()` is not triggered? How do I debug?

```xml
<Table items="{myOdata>/SalesOrderSet}">
  <ColumnListItem type="Navigation" detailPress=".onPress">
    <!-- ... -->
  </ColumnListItem>
  <columns>
    <!-- ... -->
  </columns>
</Table>
```

```js
onPress: function (oEvent) {
  //This code was generated by the layout editor.
  alert("In");
  var loOverview = "Data from Overview";
  var oItem = oEvent.getSource();
  var loRouter = sap.ui.core.UIComponent.getRouterFor(this);
  loRouter.navTo("Detail", {
    value: oItem.getBindingContext("oModel").getPath().substr(1)
  });
},
```

Comment: I tried using StandardListItem instead of ColumnListItem, the 'press' Event is triggered. I am able to retrieve the item using getSource().getBindingContext("myOdata").getPath(). Why it did not work for ColumnListItem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The press function is not working as you have not written the correct handler for it. As per your code, the handler is written for `detailPress`. Just a typo, change the handler to `press` and it should just work.

Current:

```xml
<ColumnListItem type="Navigation" detailPress=".onPress">
```

Change required:

```xml
<ColumnListItem type="Navigation" press=".onPress">
```

Comment: Initially, I used press="onPress" but it did not work so I switched to detailPress="onPress" but still did not working. After posting my question here, I created another project and name space to try out this ColumnListItem control. But it worked this time round but I did not see anything difference from the same code that I have problem earlier. I only remember the earlier version, the list does not have a ">" to the right of each item of the list. Any hint we can get from this?

Comment: `press="onPress"` would have not worked if the ListType was 'Inactive' which is the default list type. More details here: https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.ListType

Comment: What is the difference between "Navigation" and "Active"? It looks like both can work.

Comment: Navigation shows a icon : `>` depicting that it will take you somewhere. Active meaning you can press and click will perform some operation. Its more of semantics.

Comment: @RichardNg Please accept this answer to let others know that this issue is resolved now. See _[What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)_

Answer (score 0):

the property that you should bind on the Table control is `itemPress` and your ColumnListItem need to have the type equals to `Navigation`

Can you check those?

Comment: itemPress is not a valid Event. detailPress is valid Event but nothing happened when I clicked on the detail line.